# Unable to build Kubernetes code on GCP VM

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to build Kubernetes code for the first time, just to play with it, and out of curiosity, but it is getting stuck at a point. I have created a free trial GCP account. I am trying to remain in the free trial so created a g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory) VM with CentOS 8 and 30 GB storage. In order to try and give it a bit of more memory swap space, I also created a 4 GB swap space from disk. Next I have been following the intructions from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q91iZywBzew and http://ianchak.com/buildingk8s/3_BUILD_AND_PR.md.

I was able to get all the steps(i hope) working till before the "## Build Kubernetes" section, but when i finally run the "time make quick-release" step, it begins and then sort of gets stuck/remains at the "cluster/gce/gci/mounter" line. 
Here is the screenshot of where the build remains(i tried waiting for a few hours):

[image]

If I press ctrl+break to try and stop the execution, it shows the message :

[image]

Comment: You are making life exceptionally difficult trying to build kubernetes on such a small machine, as the build cobbles RAM and CPU like crazy. Is there a great reason you haven't tried to build it using a local virtual machine, or your local Linux machine?

Comment: Also, please don't post code as screenshots; it's bad for search discovery, makes them hard to read, and is explicitly called out as a no-no in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: I just tested this on suggested minimum machine (`n1-standard-8`)  in the tutorial and the process finished in around 20min. Can you please test it locally or try the stronger machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @acid_fuji, I changed the VM machine type to n1-standard-8. Build completed in 9 mins and 46 seconds!

Comment: I`m glad it helped. Small tip for the future, if the community helped you with something, give the opportunity to place their own answer :)

Comment: Also, if this answer works for you, please mark it as accepted, even if it's your own answer (and especially if there are no other answers). This will let the community know that the question has a good answer.